# how to read environment variable in distribution of electron app

Tags: electron, environment, builder

electronic app has the following package.json:

**package.json**

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  }
```

I can read environment variables by running the electron app with `npm start`.

```js
process.env.JAVA_HOME
```

the result exists.

However, if I create a distribution of the electronic app with the `npm run dist` command and then run the distribution app, I cannot read the environment variable.

the result is `undefined`

How can I read environment variables in distribution of the electronic app?

I'm working on macOS Monterey

Comment: I'm having the same issue and can't run java from exec() https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/41380